# Can't receive messages in ActiveMQ Artemis through the JMX

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to get messages from the queue through the JMX, but it gives me an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getBrokerId(Unknown Source)
    at jmxClientUIPConsole.JMXExample.main(JMXExample.java:93)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1083)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1353)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:920)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.ArtemisMBeanServerBuilder$MBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(ArtemisMBeanServerBuilder.java:96)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getMBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.ArtemisMBeanServerGuard.handleGetAttribute(ArtemisMBeanServerGuard.java:77)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.ArtemisMBeanServerGuard.invoke(ArtemisMBeanServerGuard.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.management.ArtemisMBeanServerBuilder$MBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(ArtemisMBeanServerBuilder.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1443)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:637)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:164)
    at jdk.remoteref/jdk.jmx.remote.internal.rmi.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttribute(RMIConnector.java:904)
    at java.management/javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:273)
    ... 2 more
```

Code ObjectName:

```
ObjectName mbeanNameQueue = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=static-broker1,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=tmp_queue2");
            org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueViewMBean queueView = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbsc, mbeanNameQueue, org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueViewMBean.class);
            System.out.println(queueView.browseAsTable());
```

Using verion:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Tried to enter in ObjectName: org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost and org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're attempting to use JMX MBean ObjectNames from ActiveMQ Classic in ActiveMQ Artemis. That won't work. The management API in ActiveMQ Artemis is different from ActiveMQ Classic.

You can find general information about the ActiveMQ Artemis management API in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html). To learn more about the various available management operations, see [the Javadoc for these interfaces](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/package-summary.html). They are located in the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management` package and they are named with the word `Control` at the end (e.g. `ServerControl`, `QueueControl`, etc.).

In your case, you'll probably want to use the [`browse()` operation on the `QueueControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#browse()).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  and what then MBean will be in Artemis for message reading?  I can't find information anywhere

Comment: Any feedback here? Did this get you going in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, the direction vector became clear, but I ran into a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76058228/how-to-translate-compositedata-class-objects-into-message-class-objects-in-art