# How to translate CompositeData[] class objects into Message class objects in ActiveMQ Artemis JMX?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I'm using JMX to connect to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue via the `QueueControl` class and its browse method, which returns a `CompositeData` array, but I can't get the individual headers with the get methods as there aren't any. Please tell me how to get not the whole body of the headers, but certain fields via JMX on Artemis

I also tried the `listMessage` method, but it gives an incomplete list of headers and does not display the body of the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to getting the message details out of the `CompositeData` is the [`CompositeDataConstants`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/message/openmbean/CompositeDataConstants.html) class.

If I sent a message like this:

```java
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
      Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      Session session = connection.createSession();
      MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("myQueue"));
      TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
      message.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue("myReplyTo"));
      message.setText("myText");
      message.setStringProperty("myKey1", "myValue1");
      message.setStringProperty("myKey2", "myValue2");
      messageProducer.send(message);
      connection.close();
```

You could browse the queue and deserialize the message data, e.g.:

```java
      QueueControl queueControl = ...
      CompositeData[] messages = queueControl.browse();
      for (CompositeData message : messages) {
         System.out.println("JMSMessageID: " + message.get(CompositeDataConstants.USER_ID));
         System.out.println("Destination: " + message.get(CompositeDataConstants.ADDRESS));
         System.out.println("Text: " + message.get(CompositeDataConstants.TEXT_BODY));
         System.out.println("DeliveryMode: " + ((Boolean) message.get(CompositeDataConstants.DURABLE) ? "persistent" : "non-persistent"));
         TabularData stringProps = (TabularData) message.get(CompositeDataConstants.STRING_PROPERTIES);
         for (CompositeData o : (Collection<CompositeData>) stringProps.values()) {
            System.out.println(o.get("key") + ": " + o.get("value"));
         }
      }
```

Which would print something like this:

```
JMSMessageID: ID:41171b0e-dfae-11ed-9217-3ce1a1d12939
Destination: myQueue
Text: myText
DeliveryMode: persistent
JMSReplyTo: queue://myReplyTo
myKey1: myValue1
myKey2: myValue2
__AMQ_CID: 41123909-dfae-11ed-9217-3ce1a1d12939
```

If you don't want to use the constants directly you can find their respective values [here](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/constant-values.html#org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.message.openmbean.CompositeDataConstants.ADDRESS).

Keep in mind that the returned data may be truncated due to the `management-message-attribute-size-limit`. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-settings.html) explains this setting:

> `management-message-attribute-size-limit` is the number of bytes collected from the message for browse. This is relevant for the `browse` and `list` management methods exposed on the queue control. Message attributes longer than this value appear truncated. Default is `256`. Use `-1` to switch this limit off. Note that memory needs to be allocated for all messages that are visible at a given moment. Setting this value too high may impact the browser stability due to the large amount of memory that may be required to browse through many messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't find in this class and in the documentation how to get the DeliveryMode and ReplyTo headers

Comment: The "DeliveryMode" in JMS dictates how the broker will store the message (i.e. persist it to disk or not). This is represented by the "durable" message header (i.e. `CompositeDataConstants.DURABLE`). My answer demonstrates how to retrieve this information.

Comment: The JMS "ReplyTo" can be found in the text of "PropertiesText" of the `CompositeData` (i.e. `CompositeDataConstants.PROPERTIES`) as `JMSReplyTo`. I'll update my answer to include this as well as example output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And how then to output a separate JMSReplyTo header and a separate HashMap with a pair of key values of all properties that we ourselves can set through the setStringProperty method?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: FWIW, all I'm doing is looking at the `CompositeData[]` returned by the `browse()` method in a debugger and then writing code to get the pieces you ask about. Ostensibly you could do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm very stupid today, I'm sorry