# How to send and subtract message to ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMX?

Tags: java, jmx, activemq-artemis

I can't find any documentation anywhere on how to send and subtract a message to an ActiveMQ Artemis queue via JMX

I tried via the same MBean from ActiveMQ "Classic," but those MBeans are not intended to be used in ActiveMQ Artemis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find general information about the ActiveMQ Artemis management API in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html). To learn more about the various available management operations, see [the Javadoc for these interfaces](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/package-summary.html). They are located in the `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management` package and they are named with the word `Control` at the end (e.g. `ServerControl`, `QueueControl`, etc.).

To send a message to a queue you can use the [`sendMessage()` operation on the `QueueControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#sendMessage(java.util.Map,int,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) or you could also use the same operation on the corresponding [`AddressControl`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/AddressControl.html#sendMessage(java.util.Map,int,java.lang.String,boolean,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) and the message will be routed to the queues on the address according to the configured routing-type.

By "subtract" I assume you mean *delete* and you can do that with a couple of different operations:

- [`removeMessage(long)`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#removeMessage(long)) - Removes the message corresponding to the specified message ID. To be clear, this message ID is the *internal* ID, not the JMSMessageID. If you were browsing messages as we discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76058228/how-to-translate-compositedata-class-objects-into-message-class-objects-in-art) you could get this ID by looking at the "messageID" value (i.e. `CompositeDataConstants#MESSAGE_ID`)
- [`removeMessage(String)`](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#removeMessages(java.lang.String)) - Removes all the message corresponding to the specified filter. Using `null` or an empty filter will remove all messages from this queue.