# How to get JMSReplyTo and JMSCorrelationID from CompositeData[]?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76058228/how-to-translate-compositedata-class-objects-into-message-class-objects-in-art) where all the `String` properties of a message are printed, but I don't understand how to get (display) *exactly* `JMSReplyTo` and separately `JMSCorrelationID`.

I tried the key value through the pass, but I get a lot of extra headers, and I need to get the name

```java
for (CompositeData o : (Collection<CompositeData>) stringProps.values()) {
    System.out.println(o.get("key") + ": " + o.get("value"));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the value of the "key" to ensure it's something you want to print, e.g.:

```java
for (CompositeData o : (Collection<CompositeData>) stringProps.values()) {
   Object key = o.get("key");
   if (key.equals("JMSReplyTo") || key.equals("JMSCorrelationID")) {
      System.out.println(key + ": " + o.get("value"));
   }
}
```